# Cannot set multi-select option field when creating record in Dynamics 365 XRM Web API

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, odata, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am attempting to create a record using the Dynamics 365 Web API. The field trying to be set is a multi-select option and is supposed to take an array of integers.  The value being passed in is an array of integers (2nd screenshot), and yet I am getting the following error:

> An unexpected 'StartArray' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'PrimitiveValue' node was expected.?
>
> [image: **enter image description here**]
>
> [image]

Below is the code being used, identifying the line causing trouble.

```
var data = {
            "title": "sample title",
            "new_f1": f1_value,
            "new_meetingdate": meeting_date,
            "new_trainingmodules": training_modules, // Error on this line
            "new_annualnoticedate": annual_notices,

        }  

        Xrm.WebApi.createRecord("incident", data).then(
            function success(result) {
                alert("Case record created.");
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("error.message);
                // handle error conditions
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to send Multi-select optionset attribute as an array in payload, just send it as comma separated string value.

```
var training_modules = "100000001, 100000002";
.
.
.

"new_trainingmodules": training_modules,
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/multi-select-picklist#setting-multi-select-picklist-values)

> **Setting multi-select picklist values**
>   With the Web API, you set the values by passing a string containing comma separated number values as shown in the following example:
>
> **Request**
>
> ```
> POST [organization uri]/api/data/v9.0/contacts HTTP/1.1
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
> OData-Version: 4.0
>
> {
>     "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.contact",
>     "firstname": "Wayne",
>     "lastname": "Yarborough",
>     "sample_outdooractivities": "1, 9"
> }
> ```